Parse log with Grok
I am new with Grok and i have a log message. I need to parsing to 3 fields : IP / Date & time and the rest. Please give me advice.
here is what i tried, can not split date / time & the rest message
Thanks everyone

You can see some default pattern in grok-pattern.json
First you need to define the custom pattern called DATESTAMP_CUSTOM to match your time string.
%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}


And use it in grok pattern
%{IPORHOST:ip} - - \[%{DATESTAMP_CUSTOM:dts}\] %{GREEDYDATA:rest}

Output in grok debugger
[
  {
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "dts": "31/Mar/2022:21:40:35 -0500",
    "rest": "\"POST /dispatcher-918200/dispReceiver HTTP/1.1\" 200 "
  }
]



Add by logstash
Write a pattern file that contained the line
# contents of ./patterns/datestamp_custom:
DATESTAMP_CUSTOM %{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}

Use patterns_dir setting to tell logstash where your custom patterns directory is.
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
    match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:ip} - - \[%{DATESTAMP_CUSTOM:dts}\] %{GREEDYDATA:rest}" }
  }
}


Hi, i tried %{IPORHOST:ip} - - [%{DATESTAMP_CUSTOM:dts}] %{GREEDYDATA:rest} but it does not work. can you help, thanks

Did you add custom pattern with DATESTAMP_CUSTOM ? my grok debugger link is updated, please check

Hi, i tried but still does not work

Hi, i tried grokdebugger with your grok but it does not show any any result

I update the image with add custom pattern in grok debugger, please make sure you add it before you used %{DATESTAMP_CUSTOM}.

Hi, I have another message log as below
"Jul 11, 2022 6:44:49 AM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi getDefaultTrustStore INFO: Initializing with trust store at path: /app/ctrlm-agent/ctm/cm/AFT/JRE_11/lib/security/cacerts"
I need to filter Loglevel: INFO / message "org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi getDefaultTrustStore" / and the rest. Please help check my Grok below and give me advice
(?%{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day}, %{YEAR:year} (?%{TIME} AM|PM))) %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}

just use GREEDYDATA before the LOGLEVEL like this %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, %{YEAR} %{TIME} (AM|PM) %{GREEDYDATA:package} %{LOGLEVEL:severity}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}
